# (C++) tuples for bulk operations, using references when possible

Tags: c++, templates, stl, tuples

To reduce verbose code I often rely on the STL data structures such as `std::tuple` and `std::vector`, which have implementations for `operator==` ( and in general `operator<=>` ).

This helps to reduce on for loops checking each index or a sequence of if statements doing the same.

Recently, however, I wanted to try this on the following senario:

```
#include<memory>
#include<string>
#include<tuple>

struct ComplexStruct;

struct ExampleAccumulator
{
    std::string mExampleName;
    int mExampleType
    ...
    std::shared_pointer< ComplexStruct > mExampleComplex;

    bool CanBeMerged( std::string inName, int inType, std::shared_pointer< ComplexStruct > inComplex )
    {
        // Example without using STL tuples
        if( mExampleName != inName ) return false;
        if( mExampleType != inType ) return false;
        ...
        if( bool( mExampleComplex ) != bool( inComplex ) ) return false;

        ... // Advanced comparison
    }

    bool CanBeMergedShortend( std::string inName, int inType, std::shared_pointer< ComplexStruct > inComplex )
    {
        // Example using STL tuples
        auto current = __group__( mExampleName, mExampleType, ..., bool( mExampleComplex ) );
        auto other   = __group__( inName      , inType      , ..., bool( inComplex       ) );

        if( current != other ) return false;

        ... // Advanced comparison
    }
}
```

However, for `__group__`:

- I cannot use `std::tie` as some of the inputs are temporaries ( will not compile )
- I cannot use `std::make_tuple` as this would call the copy constructor which is expensive and not always public
- I cannot use `std::forward_as_tuple` as this would store `&&` to the temporaries which would lead to dangling references
- I could use a struct with `auto operator<=> const( struct const & ) = default`, but this is verbose, requires a name, which would not always be meaningful, and the correct typing ( `T const &` or just `T` ). I do use this approach when it makes sense

Finally, the solution that worked for me:

```
template< typename T >
struct Storage 
{
    using type = T;
};

template< typename T >
struct Storage< T & >
{
    using type = T const &;
};

template< typename T >
struct Storage< T && >
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename... Args> constexpr
std::tuple< typename Storage< Args >::type ...> special_tie( Args && ... args) noexcept
{
    return {args...};
}
```

- Is this safe ( dangling references )?
- Is there STL functionality which does this?

In essence, I would like to create a tuple which stores `const &` if possible otherwise just the plain type ( not `&&` ).

Comment: The return type can be just `std::tuple<Args...>`. For `T &&` it will store `T`, and for `T &` it will store `T &` as is (no `const`, but much less typing).

Comment: [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) might be used for the `std::make_tuple` case, to avoid copy.

Comment: Do you really need the same tuples after the comparison `if( current != other ) return false;` has been done? If not, you _could_ use `if( std::forward_as_tuple(lhs...) != std:.forward_as_tuple(rhs...) ) return false;`